# How to show this flat list properly?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, hierarchical-data

```
LIST ONE                    LIST TWO

[ ] Parent 1                - Entry (from Child 1)
    [X] Child 1             - Entry (from Child 1)
        [ ] ChildChild 1    - Entry (from ChildChild 1)
    [ ] Child 2
```

- **LIST ONE** contains hierarchical data. We display it in a GridView, which supports a hierarchical data.
- **LIST TWO** contains flat data. We display that in a GridView either.

If its `SelectedItem` changes **LIST TWO**'s ItemsCollection changes, either. **LIST TWO** contains a merged collection of entries from *Child 1* (`SelectedItem`) and all its children (So *Child 1* and *ChildChild 1*).

The problem we're facing is, that we need to show the user which are the entries (**LIST TWO**) of the currently selected item from **LIST ONE**.

We've been discussing for a while and brought out the following solutions:

1. We could color the entries which regard to the currently selected item.
2. We could implement a tab control: one tab shows all the entries and another one just the ones of the selected item.
3. We could put a check box there which hides the children entries when it gets (un-)checked
4. We could mark the items with an additional column. When an entry regards to the selected item, there could be a checked check box.

All of those solutions are actually the same. The only question is: is there a more elegant solution? I've been thinking for quite a while, but there doesn't come any off the top of my head. Maybe you faced similar problems.

**PS: Does somebody know a more proper title?**

Comment: Should LIST TWO have a Child 2 in it? you have two Child 1's at the moment

Comment: I updated my post. In this merged **LIST TWO** should just be the `SelectedItem`'s (Child 1) entries and all entries of all the children of the `SelectedItem`. So overall all entries of *Child 1* and *ChildChild 1*. But not of *Child 2*, because it isn't a child element. It's a sister element.

Comment: If you select parent, you have all entries, right ? So why not, when the user click, have all nodes whose entries are used to be shown as selected ? Or shown with, say, a small magnifier on their right, and this magnifier is shown on top of list two ? You could have a property 'Magnified' + a DataTrigger in the item template...

Comment: Well, the entries list won't be that small. So our target is to reduce the amout of entries, the farer you dig into the hierarchy. And multiple selection isn't an option either - for technical reasons. Isn't the idea with the magnifier the same as coloring the regarding entries? Sorry if I didn't understand your approach.